# Android MediaStyle NotificationCompat displays 3 actions maximum

Tags: android, action, android-notifications

I have 2 problems with my NotificationCompat.Builder set up as MediaStyle :

1)  I set up 5 actions and only 3 are displayed in the expanded notification. (The first 3 displayed actions are working fine).

2)  None action is displayed in the compact notification though I set up 1 action.

I'm testing on a Samsung S4 on Lollipop 5.1.1 (Cyanogen) and my app uses support library 23.2.1

Below is my NotificationCompat.Builder :

```
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(act)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
            .setContentTitle(podcastName)
            .setContentText(episodeName)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setContentIntent(activityMainPI)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .addAction(previousAction)
            .addAction(playAction)
            .addAction(nextAction)
            .addAction(rewindAction)
            .addAction(forwardAction)
            .setStyle(new MediaStyle()
                            .setShowActionsInCompactView(new int[]{1})
            );
```

Comment: Post all actions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason for this problem. I used the v4 appcompat support library instead of the v7

So replacing :

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

by :

```
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
```

fixed the problem.

This also was the reason of another of my [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100611/android-mediastyle-notificationcompat-background-color/36155143#36155143) with the media style notification.

Comment: can not resolve import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Eugen, please find the first action (the others are similar) :

```
   previousPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, new Intent(TOOLS_CONST.ACTION_PREVIOUS), 0);

   previousAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_action_previous_light, null, previousPI).build();
```