# Android MediaStyle NotificationCompat background color

Tags: android, colors, notifications

I'm testing on a Samsung S4 on Lollipop 5.1.1 (Cyanogen) and my app uses support library 23.2.1

I would like to know how to change the background color of a MediaStyle NotificationCompat.

In the builder, using

```
.setColor(mNotificationColor)
```

does not change the background.

What confuses me a little bit that the android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master example provided by Google (compiled with support library 23.2.1) uses successfully the same method to change the background color.

I know that the doc says that the argument of setColor is "int: The accent color to use"  (and not the background color) but again android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master does it successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason for this problem. I used the v4 appcompat support library instead of the v7

So replacing :

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

by :

```
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
```

fixed this issue.

This also was the reason of another of my [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100245/android-mediastyle-notificationcompat-displays-3-actions-maximum/36155199#36155199) with the media style notification.

Comment: there is no such class android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat

Comment: I suppose the class though became deprecated it may be used in development for older API versions, init?

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer to this question is wrong, I wonder how it has taken 2 upvotes.
The notification background in `MediaStyle` changes on android versions below 21 regardless, The solution which `android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master` has used (which is actually `exoplayer`'s solution) is to have different media icons for android versions higher than 21.

So normally there are png files presenting media actions, but for api 21 or higher drawables would be replaced.